# give an integer number ,count the xor value from zero to the number

Tags: c++, algorithm, xor

count "0 xor 1 xor 2 xor......xor N",for instance,i give number three as N , the program should return 0,now i put my code to the online jundge  ,the result is time limt exceed,i can hardly find where the error is  ,can any one give me some advice,thanks in advance.

```
 long long xorSum(long long  x) {   
   long long j =0;//we supposed x is big enough ,less than 10^18.
   for (long long i=1 ;i<=x;i++) {
     j  ^= i;
   }
    return j;
  }
```

Comment: There is no "error", it's just not fast enough -- hence *time limit exceeded*.  So look for a pattern, and see if you can exploit it to compute the same (correct) answer, but faster.

Comment: You should state the source of the problem and provide a link.

Comment: @j_random_hacker,er,can you give more detials,i dont know how to optimize it by myself  ,thanks .

Comment: Try a few consecutive numbers.  E.g. take 1000, XOR it with 1001, then with 1002, then with 1003, then with 1004.  What do you get after each operation?  Is there a pattern?

Comment: Fun fact: If x is 10^18, and you can loop a billion times a second (e.g. 3 cycles on a 3 GHz machine, which is very optimistic) this program will take 10^9 seconds (31.7 years) to run. Also, long long's maximum value is 2^127 - 1, and passing it in would take [over 300 billion times the age of the universe](https://www.google.com/search?q=(((2%5E127+-+1)+%2F+10%5E9)+seconds)+%2F+13.785e9+years).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple logic, which work in O(1)

```
long long xorSum(long long k) {
    switch (k % 4) {
        case 0: return k;
        case 1: return 1;
        case 2: return k + 1;
        case 3: return 0;
    }
}
```

Proof, using induction: From, 1 to 4, we can easily see that the logic is correct. Assuming that the above logic is correct until a number `x`, which `x % 4 = 3`, so the current sum is 0.

- Starting from `x + 1` which `(x + 1) % 4 = 0`, so binary representation is always `xxx00` (`xxx` represents any binary number), so xor with last sum, which is 0 we will get `xxx00`.
- The next number will have the form `xxx01` -> the xor will be `xxx00 xor xxx01 = 00001`.
- From `xxx01` to `xxx10` -> xor will be `00001 xor xxx10 = xxx11`
- From `xxx10` to `xxx11` -> xor will be `xxx11 xor xxx11 = 00000` -> Notice `xxx11 % 4 = 3` which restarts the whole sequence and completes the proof.

Comment: can you please explain the approach

Comment: @singhiskng added my proof :)

Comment: @PhamTrung  thank you !the solution is so smart and clean  :)